# Using LINQ to optimize time loop

Tags: c#, linq

I have a settings table with two columns, "Name" and "Value":

```
Name       | Value
-----------+-------
start_time | 9:30
end_time   | 4:30
length     |   30
```

I also have a result set that gives the number of appointments per time period:

```
count | time
------+--------
1     | 09:30
2     | 12:00
3     | 14:00
4     | 15:30
```

And I need to show all the time slots between start_time and end_time, with their number of appointments like this:

```
(1) 09:30
    10:30
    11:00
    11:30
(2) 12:00
    12:30
    13:00
    13:30
(3) 14:00
    14:30
    15:00
(4) 15:30
```

Here's what I got:

```
// data is the result of WebMatrix.Data.Database.Query
public void PrepareHTML(dynamic data) 
{
    StringBuilder SB = new StringBuilder("");
    TimeSpan time = StartTime; // Start/EndTime are `TimeSpan`s defined in another place

    // loop from StartTime to EndTime in 30 min increments
    while(time <= EndTime)
    {
        String t = String.Format(@"{0:hh\:mm}", time);

       try
       {
           var d = GetThisTime(t,data);
           SB.AppendFormat("<option value=\"{0}\">({1}) {0}</option>", t, d["count"]); // error is here: Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'object'
       }
       catch
       {
           SB.AppendFormat("<option value=\"{0}\">{0}</option>", t);
       }

        time = time.Add(Length);
    }
    H = SB.ToString();
}
public IEnumerable<dynamic> GetThisTime(String time, IEnumerable<dynamic> data)
{
    return from a in data
           where time.CompareTo(new TimeSpan(a.time)) == 0
           select a;
}
```

Update:
The 'error' I put in comments was not apparent, so I will duplicate here:
I get an error at

```
SB.AppendFormat("<option value=\"{0}\">({1}) {0}</option>", t, d["count"]);
```

The error is:

> Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'object'

Since it seems to be unclear: I do not want the count of the IEnumerable, I want the count column of the data set. See the second table above.

Comment: Does it work? If not, what does it produce? What would you like instead?

Comment: `GetThisTime` return `IEnumerable`, so it collection, if you want _Count_ of them you need use linq [_Count_](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb535181(v=vs.110).aspx) method like `d.Count()`

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen in code comment: `// error is here: Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'object'`

Comment: I don't want to count the items in the IEnumerable. I have a count column that I want to get the data from. See the second table from the top.

Comment: So this is not actually *optimizing* something at all, this is about making something compile to begin with? Since you haven't posted what the type of `GetThisTime` is, it's impossible to know how to provide any help. Have you tried just `d.Count` ?

Comment: count column where? :-) in object in data?

Comment: @TravisHeeter what should return `GetThisTime`?

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen Actually GetThisTime is there, in my code. However it seems there should be a Lambda expression that will accomplish this easier.

Comment: So you get back an `IEnumerable` and you want the number of items it returned? How about `d.Count()`? Though that `dynamic` in there may throw a spanner in the compiler when it comes to applying extension methods. You may have to do `((IEnumerable<object>)d).Count()`

Comment: I'm assuming that you get the error at runtime?
It would be helpful to see the calling code.

In the code above, d is a dynamic object, which means the type is determined at runtime. From the error, I'd say you are probably calling the method with an object that cannot be indexed using [].

Comment: @Kif, in code above _d_ is `IEnumerable<dynamic>` not simple _dynamic_

Comment: @Grundy, yes, my mistake, I didn't see that the code is run on d, not on data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now `GetThisTime` return `IEnumerable<dynamic>`, so it collection, but you try use it like object. Anyway you need get object first, for example with [First](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb291976(v=vs.110).aspx) or [FirstOrDefault](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb340482(v=vs.110).aspx) and only then try get property value.

You can a bit change your `GetThisTime` proc, so you not use result except in one place you can simple return count what you need like this

```
public dynamic GetThisTime(String time, IEnumerable<dynamic> data)
{
    return (from a in data
           where time.CompareTo(new TimeSpan(a.time)) == 0
           select a["count"]).FirstOrDefault();
}
```

and use it like

```
SB.AppendFormat("<option value=\"{0}\">({1}) {0}</option>", t, GetThisTime(t,data));
```

**NOTE:** your expression seems wrong: you try compare string with TimeSpan

**UPDATE:** i think you need a bit change your logic like

```
public void PrepareHTML(dynamic data) 
{
    StringBuilder SB = new StringBuilder("");
    TimeSpan time = StartTime; // Start/EndTime are `TimeSpan`s defined in another place

    // loop from StartTime to EndTime in 30 min increments
    while(time <= EndTime)
    {
        String t = String.Format(@"{0:hh\:mm}", time);
        var d = GetThisTime(t,data); // Send the String instead of TimeSpan
        if(d != null){
           SB.AppendFormat("<option value=\"{0}\">({1}) {0}</option>", t, d); // error is here: Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'object'
       }
       else
       {
           SB.AppendFormat("<option value=\"{0}\">{0}</option>", t);
       }

        time = time.Add(Length);
    }
    H = SB.ToString();
}

public object GetThisTime(String time, IEnumerable<dynamic> data)
{
    return (from a in data
           where time == a.time
           select a["count"]).FirstOrDefault();
}
```

Comment: This fixes the error, but I get a list of all times like this `() ##:##`. Meaning the number of appointments is empty for each time, even the ones with appointments. It seems like this is bypassing the try catch, and getting an empty result no matter what, whereas it should not even put parenthesis if there are no appointments at that time.

Comment: @TravisHeeter, are you see _note_ in answer?

Comment: @TravisHeeter, you have a wrong logic in your `PrepareHTML` why you expect exceptions insted simple check that it times first in interval?

Comment: Your Update worked. The only issue was formatting the time as a new TimeSpan in `where time = new TimeSpan(a.time)`: I ended up comparing the Strings instead of `TimeSpan`s. I'll edit your answer to use that instead.